# Ionic / Angular 5 - Storage get in external function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, storage

I am trying to get a value with ionic local storage. But it always returns `undefined`. This is my code snippet.

```
    getValue(k) {
        this.storage.get(k).then((val) => {
            console.log(val);
            return val;
        });
    }

let test = this.storageprovider.getValue('test');
```

The `test` is always `undefined`.

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Comment: Did `console.log(val)`(According to your code)  print `undefined` ?

Comment: No, Its undefined because its another scope I guess, but question is how can i define this variable global

Answer (score 0):

See code inside the getValue fn is returning the promise. So you need to use

```
this.storageprovider.getValue('test').then((result)=>{
   console.log(result);
});

async getLocalData(){
   let test = await this.storageprovider.getValue('test');
}
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do that?